# How to plot location in Google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have Google map in my android application which has many location that will be shown as marker on map. If i do that, the map will be slow when loading more location on map from web service. Can i use Google fusion table instead?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map clustering, to achieve better performance. There are some libraries for clustering:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

https://github.com/weakwire/AndroidMapCluster

https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf